# I get error for accessing all mysql columns

Tags: mysql

I want to select all columns where vaules of coulmns not equal to 'na'.

Thi is the query I use for this.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_skilllist` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> 'na'
```

this is the error I get

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> '' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Can anybody help me to correct the query.

Comment: 'Column' is a reserved word.  Try 'column'

Comment: yes , I have 150 columns that's why I use column keyword.

Comment: First: you don't have access to columns as if they were rows. Second: how come people don't read and comprehend what the question is? It's pretty clear, collect all columns which aren't null. However, you can't do it in a single query. You can specify which columns to select. You can't specify which ones NOT to select if they were null. It seems your schema is wrong. You obviously need to select "columns" as if they were rows. That simply implies that your 150-column table should actually be a table with 150 records.

Comment: +1 rethink your schema. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

`column` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), it should be between backticks to make it work (or better, use something else for your column name):

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_skilllist` WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(`column`) <> 'na'
```

Comment: I tried above but I get the error` #1054 - Unknown column 'column' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: @N.B. can you please explain that?

Comment: What, why you didn't answer to the question? Just read it again, it's pretty much clear what the OP wants to do. Backticking the reserved word does not answer the question. It just produces another error.

Answer (score -1):

column is a keyword for mysql so avoid using it for your column name. 
try this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_skilllist` 
WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL 
AND TRIM(`column`) != 'na';
```

please see the demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c943/1)

> [**HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c943/1) **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c943/1)**

Comment: I get the following `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '!='na' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: could you please provide the reason to downvote?. that SQL is working perfectly and you can see the demo on sql fiddle I've provided.